# Unity: How to pass self as a parameter of another method c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

let's say I have the following code :

```
public Text someText;

someText.text = ReturnSomeText();
```

very simple.
now here is ReturnSomeText() method code :

```
public string ReturnSomeText()
{
    // I want to do some stuff here before returning the text like :
    // I want to set fontstyle of someText to Bold
    // from outside I can just simply set someText.fontstyle = FontStyle.Bold;

   // I have a solution, but I don't like it :
   // I can change ReturnSomeText() structure to ReturnSomeText(Text _text)
   // Then I can say someText.text = ReturnSomeText(someText);
   // but this is not what I want
   // because I am planning to call/use this method many times in many occasions, 
   // I don't want to adjust for every time
   // is there any other smart way.

    return "Hello World";
}
```

Thank You

Comment: What you want?Do you want to set the text property in ReturnSomeText() method?

Comment: Yes @ArslanAli I am

Comment: Call it as `someText.text = ReturnSomeText(someText);` then declare it as public `string ReturnSomeText(Text text){}`. You can then modify the `text` param in the `ReturnSomeText` function

Comment: you are right @ArslanAli I can do it as you suggested, but that will take me to put/re-write someText back again into the method. I need to call ReturnSomeText more than thousand times, I don't want to modify each line separately, If you know what I mean... I want to do it smart way if possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Create UI Text **Prefab**

Create empty GameObject and attach following script to it. Assign Text prefab to this script (MyText.cs) while you have to attach your own font or whatever you want to use in unity Built-in type. After that you can Instantiate Text prefab dynamically using code and set as well position for describing to 1000 a lot of texts as well I have done for only one prefab.

**MyText.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MyText : MonoBehaviour {

    class TextProperty
    {
        public Font font { set; get; }
        public string textValue { set; get; }
        public FontStyle fontStyle { set; get; }
        public int fontSize { set; get; }
    }
    public Font font;
    public Text t;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        var yourT = Instantiate(t, t.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Text;
        yourT.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform, false);
        this.SetTextProps(yourT, this.ReturnSomeText());
    }
    void SetTextProps(Text yourText, TextProperty tp)
    {
        yourText.text = tp.textValue;
        yourText.font = tp.font;
        yourText.fontStyle = tp.fontStyle;
        yourText.fontSize = tp.fontSize;
    }
    TextProperty ReturnSomeText()
    {
        TextProperty tp = new TextProperty();
        tp.font = font;
        tp.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        tp.textValue = "Hello World";
        tp.fontSize = 20;
        return tp;
    }
}
```

Create Many Methods of type `ReturnSomeText(...)` those will have some parameter for more texts to differentiate or whatever properties you would like to assign them While for-each different `Text` you must have prefab as well as public Declare Text and assign through inspector with font as while set property to it using `ReturnSomeText()` type new method.
These things worked well while you are working over dynamic level of objects.